# NFC Android application is started twice

Tags: android, nfc

I'm developing application that read from NFC cards.
The problem is as folows:
User started application with tap on app icon.
Application is ready to scan NFC card, implementing foreground dispatch system:

```
//Initialize Foreground NFC Dispatch System
mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
context=this;
mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, 
getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
try {
ndef.addDataType("*/*");    /* Handles all MIME based dispatches.
                           You should specify only the ones that you need. 
*/
}
catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
}
mFilters = new IntentFilter[] { ndef, };
mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { MifareClassic.class.getName() } 
};
```

In manifest I have:

```
<activity
android:name="com.d_logic.cardcontrol.SplashScreenActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
    <meta-data>
    <android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED">
    <android:resource="@xml/techlist"/>
</activity>
```

Application is started, and after while user press home button.
After that with running application in background, user start application again, but this time with NFC card.

At this time I have TWO instances of same application running.

How can I prevent second start of application, but still keep ability to start application with NFC card?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

avoid twice using this logics :

```
//put here in variable global 
private long twiceCall;
private static final int time_interval = 1500;

// and put this to avoiding twice calling
if (twiceCall + time_interval > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        // If get the second time..
} else {
        // Get the first time..
}
twiceCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of

```
android:launchMode:"standard/singleTop/singleTask/singleInstance"
```

in the manifest to ensure that the same instance of the Activity is just brought to the front and passed the new Intent. Which mode you choose depends on your exact use case.

"singleTop" or "singleTask" will probably work for your NFC use case.